# Will a batsman be out caught if the ball hits something in the air?

Tags: rules, cricket

If a ball hits something in the air (e.g. helicam or any bird) and is then caught, will the batsman be given out?

Answer (score 1):

In short for hitting a bird it would be considered out as under [law 23](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-23-dead-ball/) the ball would not be dead.

With regards helicam that is a little more tricky.  I am trying to look for the regulations regarding its use.  I suspect it would be a dead ball, but under simple law it would also be out.

Comment: I think you're right about something like a heli-cam or spider-cam, if these are in place regulations should also be in place for those matches. There's also the concept of local rules, dealing with things like trees in the playing area etc.

Answer (score -2):

I think this happened once in the IPL. The ball hit the helicam and went for a four, and the batsman was given four runs. It should have been a dead ball but the umpire gave him a bit of a leeway there.

Comment: Could you detail which match this happened in?

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't actually a wicket but it went for a four. While cricketing rules state that the ball should be declared dead, the umpire gave a little leeway there. The umpire's word is final, after all. The match was DD vs RCB and Yuvraj Singh was batting.

Comment: I suggest you edit that extra information into the answer rather than leaving it as a comment.